# Python regex to get everything until the first dot in a string

Tags: python, regex

```
find = re.compile("^(.*)\..*")
for l in lines:
    m = re.match(find, l)
    print m.group(1)
```

I want to regex whatever in a string until the first dot.

in `a@b.c`, I want `a@b`
in `a@b.c.d`, I want `a@b`
in `a@b.c.d.e`, I want `a@b`

What my code is giving me...

- `a@b.c` prints `a@b`
- `a@b.c.d` prints `a@b.c`
- `a@b.c.d.e` prints `a@b.c.d`

what should find be so that it only gets a@b?

Comment: What should happen if there is no dot? Do you want the whole string or the empty string as match(or something else)?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

By default all the quantifiers are greedy in nature. In the sense, they will try to consume as much string as they can. You can make them reluctant by appending a `?` after them:

```
find = re.compile(r"^(.*?)\..*")
```

As noted in comment, this approach would fail if there is no *period* in your string. So, it depends upon how you want it to behave. But if you want to get the complete string in that case, then you can use a negated character class:

```
find = re.compile(r"^([^.]*).*")
```

it will automatically stop after encountering the first period, or at the end of the string.

---

Also you don't want to use [re.`match()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) there. [re.`search()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) should be just fine. You can modify your code to:

```
find = re.compile(r"^[^.]*")

for l in lines:
    print re.search(find, l).group(0)
```

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/9Pi76X)

Comment: Note that the two regexes do not match the same thing. The first one fails if there is no dot, while the latter always matches.

Comment: @Bakuriu Good catch. Missed it somehow :)

Answer (score 45):

You can use [`.find()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) instead of regex in this situation:

```
>>> s = "a@b.c"
>>> print(s[0:s.find('.')])
a@b
```

---

Considering the comments, here's some modification using [`.index()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) (it's similar to `.find()` except that it returns an error when there's no matched string instead of -1):

```
>>> s = "a@b.c"
>>> try:
...     index = s.index('.')
... except ValueError:
...     index = len(s)
...
>>> print(s[:index])
a@b
```

Comment: +1 - This is an excellent and efficient solution that doesn't require importing.  Nice!

Comment: This gives an odd result if there is no dot: it returns `s` without the last character. If this matter it's probably simpler to do `try: index = s.index('.') except ValueError: index = len(s)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `split` method: split the string at the `.` character one time, and you will get a tuple of (before the first period, after the first period). The notation would be:

```
mystring.split(".", 1)
```

Then you can simply create a generator that "yields" the part you are interested, and ignores the one you are not (the `_` notation). It works as follows:

```
entries = [
    "a@b.c",
    "a@b.c.d",
    "a@b.c.d.e",
    ]

for token, _ in (entry.split(".", 1) for entry in entries):
    print token
```

Output:

```
a@b
a@b
a@b
```

The documentation for the `split` method can be found [online](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> **`str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])`**
>
> Return a list of the words in the string,
>   using `sep` as the delimiter string. If `maxsplit` is given, at most
>   `maxsplit` splits are done (thus, the list will have at most `maxsplit+1`
>   elements). If `maxsplit` is not specified or -1, then there is no limit
>   on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend `partition` or `split` in this case; they work well when there is no dot.

```
text = "example@example.com"

print text.partition(".")[0]
print text.split(".", 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
data='a@b.c.d.e'
re.sub('\..*','',data)
```